# Why do I get the MySQL Error “Query was empty”?

Tags: mysql, exception

Here is my code.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) header("Location: ../");
$username = $_SESSION["user"];
$id = $_SESSION["id"];

$nume=$_POST["nume"];
$prenume=$_POST["prenume"];
$telefon=$_POST["telefon"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$adresa=$_POST["adresa"];
$ziNastere=$_POST["ziNastere"];
$poza=$_POST["poza"];

include('../conn2.php');

mysql_query("UPDATE $username SET nume=$nume,prenume=$prenume,telefon=$telefon,email=$email,adresa=$adresa,ziNastere=$ziNastere,poza=$poza
WHERE id=$id");

mysql_select_db($username);
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";

if(isset($_SESSION['id']))  unset($_SESSION['id']);
//header("Location: ../home");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I want to update a database "$username" with strings : $nume, $prenume, $telefon...
but when I click save it returns `"Error: Query was empty"` - why is this?

Comment: Ever heard of sql-injection attacks? http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have not defined the veriable $sql

```
  $sql = "UPDATE $username SET nume=$nume,prenume=$prenume,telefon=$telefon,email=$email,adresa=$adresa,ziNastere=$ziNastere,poza=$poza
    WHERE id=$id"
mysql_select_db($username);
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";

if(isset($_SESSION['id']))  unset($_SESSION['id']);
//header("Location: ../home");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: now it returns "Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com,adresa=Moldova,ziNastere=05.02.1992 WHERE id=1' at line 1 "

Comment: @AlexBolboșenco : Depends on your column types (I expect varchar), your data needs to be enclosed by ' and you should use mysql_real_escape_string to escape your query or better parametrized queries with PDO.